# How to register help for a custom PowerShell provider?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, powershell

I am implementing a custom PowerShell provider and I would like to add a MAML help file for the provider, which can be accessed using `Get-Help MyProvider`.

I tried to add the MAML XML file to the `ProviderConfigurationEntry` when registering the provider in a PS SnapIn. From the MSDN documentation it seems to be the right way to do this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.providerconfigurationentry_members%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I tried to specify the full path to the XML file and also only the file name.

```
public override Collection<ProviderConfigurationEntry> Providers 
{
    get 
    {
        if (this.providers == null)
        {
            if (this.helpFiles == null)
            {
                this.LoadHelpFiles();
            }

            this.providers = new Collection<ProviderConfigurationEntry> 
            {
                new ProviderConfigurationEntry(
                    "MyProvider",
                    typeof(MyProvider),
                    "MyApplication.PsProvider.dll-Help.xml")
            };
        }

        return this.providers;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. `Get-Help MyProvider` does a search on all help topics instead of displaying the provider help file and the help file is not listed in `Get-Help -Category provider`.

How to register the MAML file as the provider's help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out that the name of the provider was misspelled in the MAML file.

The name in `/helpItems/providerHelp/Name` must match the provider name specified in the `ProviderConfigurationEntry` object. Additionally, I specified the full path to the MAML file as the third parameter of the `ProviderConfigurationEntry` constructor and it works!

Comment: The full path seems to be a bad idea.